# Как сохранить файлы на aws ec2 с помощью aws sdk .net?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, ec2

Я попытался найти любой туториал либо же статью, как это сделать с помощью aws sdk .net, но, к сожалению, не могу найти.
Пожалуйста, помогите мне с этим
Я ресерчил всю документацию aws, youtube и google, но ничего не нашел.
Мне нужно просто залить файл на aws ec2 с помощью aws sdk на с#

Comment: а чем просто SSH не нравится? Отрыл доступ по SSH и заливай что хочешь.

Comment: Верно, используйте SCP.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за ответы!
Но хотел немного уточнить, я могу через консольку по ssh зайти и залить любой файл, для меня это проблемы не составит, но мне нужно реализовать на своем сайте загрузку страниц на профиль ( собственно мне нужно не только залить, а потом как-то это и вытянуть на фронт ).
Если у вас есть какие либо сайты с информацией об этом, то, пожалуйста, скиньте мне :)

Comment: для таких дел используйте S3 - там и храните файлы. EC2 виртуалки не предназначены для хранения чего либо.

Comment: и если хотите к кому то обратиться, указывайте ник того, кому пишете @Sashok - иначе просто не будет нотификации и никто не узнает о вашем коммаентарии.

Comment: @tym32167 да, спасибо, уже реализовал с помощью s3. Ибо никаких реализаций на ec2 не нашел, увы.

Comment: Так оно и понятно, нечего сову на глобус натягивать :)